# ISP changes my IP within a session

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm using to connect to Internet through a ASDL modem + router.

Recently I noticed that when I connect to my office network through a Cisco VPN client after a while the connection is broken with a message:

```
412: remote peer doesn't respond.
```

I can reconnect successfully then with my VPN client but this disconnect happens randomly, maybe also when my kid starts using other pc connected to router but I'm not 100% sure about this.

I noticed that my IP (actually the IP assigned to the router by the ISP) is changing randomly after a while (maybe once in one hour or more often) without restarting my router. To my understanding the ISP can assign a new IP via dhcp when I make a new PPPoE connection

My question is: Can he change the assigned IP without disconnecting explicitly the PPPoE connection ? My second question: might be this the reason for the VPN connection breaking?

Comment: I bet you're missing a DSL filter somewhere.

Comment: I have the DSL filter, before the ADSL modem.

Comment: Actually this IP change I noticed recently when I started to be upset whith regular VPN connection broking. First I thought that happens when my kid starts to work on his PC connected to same router. Usually  when disconnet happened he started to do something on his PC, BUT not always that was the triggering event. After that I started to investigate this more deeply and noticed this IP change. Maybe once when router is not needed will try to test directly with DSL filter + modem + PC. If IP will change whithout a PPPoE disconnect/reconnect that is a fault needing ISP support (in my opinion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISP can reset your connection at any time, and this will probably result in a changed IP address. If your IP address changes this will certainly break your VPN connection. Your router will renew it's IP address periodically. Normally this is a transparent operation and nothing changes. Some ISPs force leases to be renegotiated on a daily basis, usually in the small hours. It's highly unlikely that your address will need to be completely renewed otherwise.

However, resetting your connection as frequently as once per hour is unlikely to be a specific action of the ISP. It's more likely that you have some fault in your land line or router, or possibly (but unlikely) a firmware incompatibility between your router and the ISPs broadband hardware.

I'd start by asking your ISP to test your landline connection.

Comment: Could it be DHCP lease renewal triggering a reassigned IP?

Comment: @Heptite In theory it could, but address renewals will always request the existing IP address first and request a new one only if it's not available. If an ISP is forcing complete renegotiation every hour that suggests their contention is far too high and it's time to seek a new ISP.